# How to read values from a csv when the number of rows are exact for each parameter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have to run a load test on a server. The requests have to go to 2 servers in order to balance the number of requests. There are 100 household IDs also. So I have to use the first household and send the request to the first server. The second household to the second server. The third household to the first server again and 4th household to the second server. This should continue till 100 households send the requests and it will be exactly 50 requests for each server. I have created a CSV file with 2 columns. One column for Household with 100 rows and another column with 2 rows. The problem here is when the 3rd request is sent, JMeter will pick the 3rd Household but the server is blank. Is there any way to implement this using a single CSV file? I can make this work using 2 CSV files.

Please see the below Pics.

Looking at the last screen shot, the request is seen without an IP.[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jmeter scans complete row.It is not getting any value in 3rd iteration hence parameter is taking blank value .you have two option:

1.Drag drop 2 value to entire file .(not efficient though)
2.OR create separate csv file or use something like user defined variable

Comment: Thanks ABC. I have already done with 2 separate CSVs. Just wanted to know a solution with a single CSV.